# Why is [(4,4), (3)] not a descending plane partition of order 4?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to understand descending plane partitions.

According to Wolfram MathWorld,

> *A descending plane partition of order n is a two-dimensional array (possibly empty) of positive integers less than or equal to n such
>   that the left-hand edges are successively indented, rows are
>   nonincreasing across, columns are decreasing downwards, and the number
>   of entries in each row is strictly less than the largest entry in that
>   row.*

Following code written by [Fischer and Konvalinka](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01354.pdf), I have printed the 42 descending plane partitions of order 4:

[image: 42 descending plane partitions of order 4]

It seems to me as if [(4,4),(3)] satisfies the conditions of a descending plane partition, but it's not on this list. Could someone elucidate the exact part of the definition that fails for [(4,4),(3)]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition on Wolfram MathWorld is incorrect; in order for the descending plane partitions of order n to be [enumerated](https://oeis.org/A005130) as [they claim](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescendingPlanePartition.html), we need the added restriction that the first part in each row is less than or equal to the length of the previous row.

3 is the first part of the second row, and 3 exceeds the length of the first row.